# How to load values from shop.metafields as options in a Shopify schema tag in liquid file?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-liquid

I am working on a Shopify theme app that requires me to load configuration options from shop.metafields and use them as selectable options in a schema tag. I have tried to generate the options array inside the schema tag using a for loop, but it doesn't seem to be correct approach. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
{% assign optionsArray = shop.metafields.global.convertcart_blockIds %};

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Recommended Products",
    "tag": "section",
    "target": "section",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "richtext",
        "id": "heading",
        "label": "Heading"
      }, {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "blockId",
        "label": "Block ID",
        "info": "Select an option",
        "options": [{% for option in optionsArray %}
            {
            "value": "{{ option }}",
            "label": "{{ option }}"
          }{% unless forloop.last %},
          {% endunless %}{% endfor %}]
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

I have tried constructing the options array in the script tag but still using that options array in schema was not possible. Can someone please help me figure out how to properly load the configuration options from shop.metafields and use them as selectable options in a schema tag? Any help or directions on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to use the theme extensions for this purpose, because existing liquid file edit and delete is limited by Shopify in future versions.

Comment: Here is asset API link which talks more about it [Link](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/other-integration-methods/asset)

Comment: @Onkar Thanks for your input. I am using theme app extension to write liquid files, but dynamically generating the options in the schema of liquid files is where I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You ae probably not accessing the metafield correctly. First off, you want to ask for the namespace.key.value, and you skipped the value part, and secondly, you can store JSON natively in metafields, meaning you could skip the whole Liquid construct of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We tried storing the JSON in metafields itself. But the schema doesn't allow dynamically assigning values to it as shown in the question. Any idea?

Comment: If you cannot render Liquid in a schema tag then you are screwed.